# Tomcat inconsistencies + uncertainty in setting paths

Tags: java, linux, jvm, amazon-ec2, tomcat6

### Background

As this is the first question I have posted, I will try to break it down as well as possible, and I apologize for any incorrect formats. I should also point out that I am brand-new to Linux, Tomcat, and Java (all within the last few weeks), so if you do have an answer please dumb it down as much as you can. Thanks!

This question is actually several questions, but I feel the issues are somehow related so I will include them all. As for my environment, I am running an EC2 Amazon Linux instance. Details returned using 
`cat /proc/version` are:

- Linux version 2.6.35.14-97.44.amzn1.x86_64
  (mockbuild@build-31006.build)
- (gcc version 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6) (GCC)

`java -version` gives me:

- java version "1.6.0_29" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
  1.6.0_29-b11)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode)

### Issue(s)

1. What would allow me to stop/restart Tomcat sometimes, but not
   others? After I change configuration parameters and need to restart
   Tomcat, I use `/etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart` or `service tomcat6
   restart` with varying degrees of success: sometimes the nice green
   OK, others the red FAILED. There seems to be no rhyme or reason to
   why it works sometimes and not others. When it doesn't work I check
   the status with `service tomcat6 status`, which yields something
   like **tomcat6 (pid ####) is running**. Also worth noting is that my
   Putty SSH session slows down *significantly* at the same time whenever
   I am unable to stop Tomcat. I literally have to wait for each keystroke to be processed!
2. I cannot use any of the JVM-specific -XX parameters. I get an error
   every time of **Could not create the Java virtual machine.** Of the
   threads I've read about this, most surround heap memory allocation
   issues, but I don't think that's my problem because when I run `java
   -XX`, which should give me a list of available commands just like `java -X` does, I simply get:

   **Unrecognized option: -XX Could not create the Java virtual machine.**

I should note that I had at least two versions of Java on this OS- it came with Open JDK, but I needed Sun Java as that was recommended for performance in Geoserver (which is the whole point of me learning all this). I read that it is not an issue to have two versions, as long as my JAVA_HOME path points to the correct directory, but is it possible that it was still somehow looking at something from the original configuration? That's what I thought, so to rule it out I did a `yum remove java`, which erased the original version (along with Tomcat due to the dependency, but whatevs, I can get it back later), ran `java -version` to make sure I still had the version I wanted. I did, then ran `java -XX`, hoping that it magically fixed itself after cleaning house with the unwanted OpenJDK removal, but NOPE, same error as before.

### Conclusions

I am now assuming that there was no issue with old paths. I've also tried changing my JAVA_HOME variable to the appropriate path (**/usr/java/jre1.6.0_29**) in every conceivable location:

- in bash_profile
- in bashrc
- java.conf
- tomcat6.conf (well, before I deleted Tomcat, that is)
- probably some other files. It's all a blur really.
- `export JAVA_HOME` in the shell

... all with zero impact, with the exception of using `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.6.0_29`. Every time I ran `echo $JAVA_HOME` I would still get the original JAVA_HOME path, which I'm pretty sure is not what I want. Even when resetting the variable was successful (via export in the shell), I still got my -XX error. I also tried setting some JAVA_OPTS parameters, specifically for memory settings, then ran an `echo $JAVA_OPTS` that returned nothing.

I have spent a solid two days on this and am about ready to give up. I would really like to avoid reinstalling and reconfiguring a whole bunch of stuff if possible, not to mention I don't even know if that would fix my problem, but I would really, really like to know WHY I having these issues and whether or not they're related, so if any of you have suggestions on this or anything in general that I'm doing incorrectly, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer (hence the comment) but... You may be interested in knowing that, on Linux, there's no need to be *root* to install Java. For example I never, ever, install Java on Linux as *root*. This may help you have a clearer picture (you won't be looking for Java files / config files everywhere on the system).  Then when you start Tomcat using, say, the *catalina.sh start* script it shall take care of setting the correct variables.  The only variable that I export myself is: *PATH=/home/travelampel/jre1.6.0_29/bin:$PATH* and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the first issue but in regard to your second issue: "I cannot use any of the JVM-specific -XX parameters.":

the environment variable CATALINA_OPTS is used by tomcat when starting the JVM. So if you want to use 512mb of heap and 128mb of perm gen space you can issue the follwing command on a bash shell to start tomcat with some custom java options.

```
#> CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m" $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run
```

you can also change the default parameters by changing CATALINA_OPTS in tomcat's startup script or you can add the paramenter to your environment (e.g. $HOME/.bashrc).

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answers. Logged in as a different user now instead of root. Copied and pasted the above code (minus the "#>") into $HOME/.bashrc and into tomcat6.conf and into /etc/init.d/tomcat6, all with no impact. I can get a correct echo from $CATALINA_OPTS, but when I add something else to the string (i.e. -Xms48m) in any of those files, nothing changes in the echo- it's always "-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m". Also, I cannot find catalina.sh anywhere. And does the "Could not create Java virtual machine" for "Unrecongnized option: -XX" even matter or should I ignore it?

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding some very basic Linux concepts here, specifically about user roles. I initially log into SSH as "ec2-user" because that's the only thing Putty accepts, then I log into it further via "jason". Why? is "ec2-user" just the name of the session? Sorry for such basic questions, and no worries if no replies as I am now likely to scrap this whole thing and just deal with not being able to set -XX options even though that will mean poorer performance in Geoserver. This is what 20 years of Windows and 3 weeks of Linux gets you! :)